# How to stop gif react-native after 1 time?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have  a gif in react and i want to stop the loop
I add an image in my view i give to the image the path of my gif and it's work but the gif go in infinite loop

Any idea to stop ?

```
<Image
    source={require('./img/anim.gif')}
 />
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Edit 
react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTGIFImageDecoder.m

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    ...
animation.repeatCount = loopCount == 0 ? 0 : loopCount; // <-- fix for single play gif from joshbedo
animation.fillMode = @"forwards"; // <-- insert this line to prevent the image disappearing after animation
```

And for android

update to the latest fresco version (androidmanifest.xml)

`compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.1.0'
 compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.1.0' 
 compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.1.0'`

Comment: I think you can also set the gif to be non-repeating in its meta tags, although that might be undesired in some use cases.