# how to run GIF once in react native IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios

I using react native to build a project for android and I use gif image inside the project and gif loop set in once in android gif run one time and it is true but in ios is loop how to force it run once time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the GIF creation the simplest way is to put the info in the GIF metadata, for example using `gifsicle` :

```
gifsicle my_gif.gif --no-loopcount > my_gif-noloop.gif
```

If you can't, you can edit `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTGIFImageDecoder.m` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738626/how-to-stop-gif-react-native-after-1-time):

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation 
    animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    ...
    animation.repeatCount = loopCount == 0 ? 0 : loopCount; // Avoid infinite loop
    animation.fillMode = @"forwards"; // avoid image to desapear after loop
```