# react native right tick animation on success

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display a green tick mark on success that will animate and will make a check mark on the screen.

Any suggestion or any library that can do this?

for more clarity please this link.
[here is the example of what i want](https://www.semanadamulherbemresolvida.com.br/checkmark/.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna use [Lottie for react-native](https://github.com/react-community/lottie-react-native), powerfull and easy to use plugin.

You can find some animations at [Lottie files](https://www.lottiefiles.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a gif, you can use an `<Image>` tag and use this gif as source.
Make sure to enable the [`gif support in android`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android).
So you can wrap your `<Image>` in a `<View>` and use the `display={condition? "flex" : "none"}` to show it whenever you want!

> P.S. You can stop gif looping [via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43738836/4565015)

Comment: MohamadKh75 i am using expo so i can't stop gif looping with your solution

Comment: Then you can use `setTimeout(setState({ showImage: "none" }), DURATION_OF_GIF);` and then show an static green check image on top of the gif (`zIndex: 1`)

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.